# Why am I getting this error Error: Transaction reverted without a reason string. When trying to swap tokens on uniswap?

Tags: blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts, uniswap

I'm trying to swap tokens on uniswap unsing hardhat's mainnet fork but I'm getting this error: `Error: Transaction reverted without a reason string`. And I don't really know why.

Here is my swap function:

```
    function swap(address router, address _tokenIn, address _tokenOut, uint _amount) public {
        IERC20(router).approve(router, _amount);
        address[] memory path;
        path = new address[](2);
        path[0] = _tokenIn;
        path[1] = _tokenOut;
        uint deadline = block.timestamp + 300;  
        IUniswapV2Router(router).swapExactTokensForTokens(_amount, 1, path, address(this), deadline);  
}
```

It is a simple function and it should work. This is how I'm calling it:

```
await arb.swap(
    uniAddress,
    wethAddress,
    daiAddress,
    ethers.utils.parseEther('0.5')
);
```

Thanks for answers!

Also here are the addresses I'm calling just to verify if they are the right ones but I'm pretty sure they are:

```
const wethAddress = '0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2';
const daiAddress = '0x6B175474E89094C44Da98b954EedeAC495271d0F';
const uniAddress = '0x7a250d5630B4cF539739dF2C5dAcb4c659F2488D';
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Weth` is different from other token, you're not able to use `swapTokensForTokens`. We must use the `swapEthForTokens` function instead, and you have to declare the data option separately.

so in your case we need to do:

Solidity code:

```
function swapEth(address router, address _tokenIn, address _tokenOut, uint _amount) public {
    IERC20(router).approve(router, _amount);
    address[] memory path;
    path = new address[](2);
    path[0] = _tokenIn;
    path[1] = _tokenOut;
    uint deadline = block.timestamp + 300;
    IUniswapV2Router(router). swapExactETHForTokens(... parameters);  
}
```

JSCode

```
const dataOption = { gasPrice: ethers.getDefaultProvider().getGasPrice(), gasLimit: 310000, value: ethers.utils.parseEther('0.5') }

await arb.swap(`enter code here`
    uniAddress,
    wethAddress,
    daiAddress,
    ethers.utils.parseEther('0.5'), // this parameter should be remove from the function declaration as well as in this Javascript
    dataOption
);
```

Comment: Ohh ok I thought those functions were for native eth but I didin't realize that uniswap v2 doesn't take the native token. You saved me hours of debugging thanks a lot!

Comment: I am facing similar problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75960250/nonfungiblepositionmanager-contract-interaction-error-transaction-reverted-with

Answer (score 0):

Just adding for reffernce but you can also get this error from provider/hardhat if the gas price you set is too high or too low. at the time of writing 5 gwei seems about right