# Nonfungiblepositionmanager Contract Interaction message: 'Error: Transaction reverted without a reason string', How to Solve it?

Tags: javascript, smartcontracts, hardhat, uniswap

In the hardhat local fork, I created the pool by interacting with factoryv3 in javascript. I approve the tokens to nonfungiblepositionmanager. I check allowance and it’s all good. I have enough funds But when I try to add liquidity it don’t work interacting Nonfungiblepositionmanager. I think It might be the upper and lower ticker causing the error. Here is the code snippet:

```
             // contract nonfungiblePosition
const NonfungiblePositionManager_abi = require('./abis/NonfungiblePositionManager.json');
const nonfungiblePositionManagerAddress = '0xC36442b4a4522E871399CD717aBDD847Ab11FE88';
const nonfungiblePositionManagerContract = new ethers.Contract(nonfungiblePositionManagerAddress, NonfungiblePositionManager_abi, account);




//Get the token addresses and decimal places for the tokens you want to provide liquidity for:
const erc20Abi = require('./abis/ERC20.json');
const DAIaddress = '0x6B175474E89094C44Da98b954EedeAC495271d0F';
const happpyaddress = 'adressss';


const DAIDecimals = 18;
const happyDecimals = 18;

//Define the fee tier for the pool:
const fee = 300; // Fee tier of 0.3%




// Calculate the desired amount of DAI for a given amount of Happy
const HappyPriceInDAI = 0.0002;
const amountHappy  = ethers.utils.parseUnits('1', happyDecimals);
const amountDAI = amounthappy.mul(ethers.utils.parseUnits(happyPriceInDAI.toString(), DAIDecimals))

const slippagePercentage = 0.995; // 0.5% slippage allowed



//add the money


const mintPool = async () => { console.log("create the pool baby, baby...");



const gasPrice = await provider.getGasPrice();

const tx = await nonfungiblePositionManagerContract.mint({
  token1: DAIaddress,
  token0: happyaddress,
  fee: fee,
  tickLower: 8872,
  tickUpper: 900000,
  amount0Desired: amounthappy,
  amount1Desired: amountDAI,
  amount0Min: amounthappy.mul(ethers.utils.parseUnits(slippagePercentage.toString(), happyDecimals)),
  amount1Min: amountDAI.mul(ethers.utils.parseUnits(slippagePercentage.toString(), DAIDecimals)),
  recipient: acct2,
  deadline: Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + 60 * 10,// 10 minutes from now,
 } ,{
  gasPrice,
  gasLimit: ethers.utils.hexlify(300000), // 300 gwei,

});

const receipt = await tx.wait();
console.log('Add liquidity transaction receipt:', receipt);
};


  
mintPool()
```

I expected to add liquidity to my new created pool using Nonfungiblepositionmanager. The price Im looking to create is 0.0002 with my new token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to edit TICK values.

I just took the following code in my example :

```
        {
           token0: WETH,
           token1: DAI,
           fee: 3000,
           tickLower: -60000,
           tickUpper: 60000,
           amount0Desired: 1000,
           amount1Desired: 1000,
           amount0Min: 0,
           amount1Min: 0,
           recipient: address(this),
           deadline: block.timestamp
    }
```

The ones from Uniswap documentation did not work with my fork of Arbitrum locally.

Answer (score 1):

For me, it did not work due to the wrong order of **token0** and **token1**

Comment: I still get same issue. What i learned i must deploy the the v3 smart contracts locally to interact with them. https://github.com/Uniswap/v3-sdk

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).